# Do getter functions need to be used within an ORM component?

Tags: coldfusion

Is it essential to use the getter functions when using internal ORM properties within ORM functions?  For example in the example below I use #person_id# instead of this.getperson_id().

```
<cfcomponent persistent="true" table="people" schema="dbo" output="false">
<cfproperty name="person_id" column="person_id" type="numeric" ormtype="int"fieldtype="id"/>

<cffunction name= "hasGifts" returntype="boolean">
<cfset gift_count = ORMExecuteQuery("SELECT COUNT(g.gift_id) FROM gifts g INNER JOIN g.people p WHERE p.person_id = '#person_id#', True )>
<cfif gift_count eq 0>
    <cfreturn false>
<cfelse>
    <cfreturn true>
</cfif>
</cffunction>
```

This seems to work fine, but I don't find it documented.  It seems like it should be allowed as there is no ambiguity and this is consistent with other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK it's fine to reference the variables directly as long as they are not lazy loaded.  Your `ORMExecuteQuery()` should use `:named` or `?` position binded value though.